# How to create a custom content type that accepts zip files and puts them in a new directory?

Tags: files

I want to simplify the workflow for putting an e-magazine on my  D7 site.

I currently have to manually upload a zip file, move it to a custom directory with in sites/default/files/emagazines/NEWCONTENT and then manually add a link to a node or content type to provide a link to the emagazine.

I imagine a custom content type that accepted zip files and then unpacked and placed the files in a directory based on the content types' name field would be a more user friendly solution, and ultimately give me a little bit more versatility. I've never really approached something like in  Drupal before, so I'm not sure where to start, but I imagine it can be done.

So,

1. Can the Drupal file field accept zip files?
2. If so, how do customize the field to extract the zip files into a custom directory?

I'm sure there's more to process, but that's where I figured I'd need to start.

Comment: Take a look of the code of https://www.drupal.org/project/imce_unzip

Comment: A custom file type using [File Entity (fieldable files)](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity)? It is fieldable (think tags etc). You can possibly alter the submit handler and use [class ArchiverZip](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.archiver.inc/class/ArchiverZip/7.x)?